# Get path, filename, sheet and address of defined name in closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel

This code can add a defined name to another workbook perfectly fine:

```
Sub AddDefinedName()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFilename As String
    Dim sSheetname As String
    Dim sRangeAddress As String

    sPath = "C:\Me\Folder"
    sFilename = "source.xls"
    sSheetname = "Sheet1"
    sRangeAddress = "$A$1:$B$5"

    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Source", _
            RefersTo:="='" & sPath & "\[" & sFilename & "]" & sSheetname & "'!" & sRangeAddress
End Sub
```

And this code allows to get all the information IF the said workbook is open:

```
Sub GetDefinedName()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFilename As String
    Dim sSheetname As String
    Dim sRangeAddress As String

    sPath = Range("Source").Parent.Parent.Path
    sFilename = Range("Source").Parent.Parent.Name
    sSheetname = Range("Source").Parent.Name
    sRangeAddress = Range("Source").Address

    MsgBox sPath
    MsgBox sFilename
    MsgBox sSheetname
    MsgBox sRangeAddress
End Sub
```

How can I get these when the workbook "source.xls" is closed (so I can open it through VBA).

Comment: I did searched but never find anything close to what I was looking for. I will read your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Name` object to get the address string, like this
(assuming you have defined the name as `Workbook` scope)

```
Dim nm as Name

Set nm = ThisWorkbook.Names("Source")
Debug.Print nm.RefersTo
```

This will give you the full path and address in the form

```
'=C:\Me\Folder\[source.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$5
```

Note: without the `'`'s if there are no spaces in the path, filename or sheet name

The above will return info for a specific named range.  if you want to get info for *all* remote references, try using

```
ThisWorkbook.LinkSources
```

This will return an array of all link sources as strings.  For links to other worksheets, it will be in the form

```
C:\Me\Folder\source.xls
```

Comment: This is excellent. It works perfectly to get the formula. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just open it and close it again, I know it's not the same as "not opening it physically" but it does the same job. Just be aware that any macros that are in the "Source" workbook's `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_close` will be fired when this code runs:

```
Sub GetDefinedName()
    Application.ScreenUpdate = False
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFilename As String
    Dim sSheetname As String
    Dim sRangeAddress As String



    sPath = Range("Source").Parent.Parent.Path
    sFilename = Range("Source").Parent.Parent.Name
    sSheetname = Range("Source").Parent.Name
    sRangeAddress = Range("Source").Address
    Application.Workbooks.Open sPath & sFilename


    MsgBox sPath
    MsgBox sFilename
    MsgBox sSheetname
    MsgBox sRangeAddress

    sFilename.close False
    Application.ScreenUpdate = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do except if "source.xls" is closed Range("Source").Parent.Parent.Path and all the others give an error.

Comment: So what your saying is you need to open the source workbook in order to get the path to the source workbook... That's impossible. You need to know where it is first!

Comment: But… Excel knows where it is! It is registered in the defined name "Source". If I go on Name Manager there is the whole path, filename, sheet and range I've set before.