# ADODB data retrieve from excel, NamedRange with worksheet scope not recognized when workbook opened

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

I'm trying to pull data from several excels into Access database. All code is written in Access. Each excel has from one to about 10 sheets where data are present. They are organized in a table. Each area that has data is NamedRange with Worksheet scope, so NamedRanges for all sheets are the same (same name and usually same range, but name is important), its just scope that is different.

I do use ADODB connection. Problem that I have is that when the workbook is opened (by other user for example), it will not recognize worksheet scope NamedRange

Connection:

```
 adocnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & FileName & ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=no; IMEX=3;"";"
 adocnn.cursorlocation = adUseClient 'tested for both server/client
```

opening recordset:

```
sheetname = "CZ00904001" & "$"
namedrange = "Version"

adors.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetname & namedrange & "]", adocnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

So `SELECT * FROM [CZ00904001$Version]` throws error run-time -2147217865 "..database engine could not find the object 'CZ00904001$Version'...."
This error occurs when workbook is opened

If it is closed, it retrieves proper data

Same with workbook scope

If I use cell info like `A1:B4` it will retrieve correct information even with open workbook, so

```
sheetname = "CZ00904001" & "$"
namedrange = "A1:B4"

    adors.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetname & namedrange & "]", adocnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

So statement `SELECT * FROM [CZ00904001$A1:B4]` retrieves data

I'm trying to figure out how to write it so it can retrieve data no matter whether workbook is open or closed by using named ranges.
Or give me a tip how to get that named range address without actually opening the workbook

I also noticed that

```
Set adors = adocnn.openschema(20)

    Do Until adors.EOF
        Debug.Print adors.Fields("Table_name")
        adors.MoveNext
    Loop
```

returns different number of records depending on whether workbook is opened or closed.

Thank you for your help

EDIT1:

So I made some tests. I created code only in excel, and source workbook

Turns out problem is somewhere within naming of sheets. I have two sheets in tested source workbook. One sheet is named CZ00904002 other one is named CZ90904002

```
adors.Open "SELECT * FROM[CZ00904002$test];",adocnn,adOpenStatic,adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

throws mentioned error **when the workbook is opened**, but

```
adors.Open "SELECT * FROM [CZ90904002$test];", adocnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

returns what I'm looking for.

I tried several different quotes combination but no luck so far.

CZ01904002 works
CZ10904002 works

it seems that it is the beginning of CZ00 that makes this error

Thank you for any suggestions how to change that SQL part for it to work. Tips so far involve opening workbook, or copying, that seems to me not elegant enough at this moment. Last resort approach

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383054/get-path-filename-sheet-and-address-of-defined-name-in-closed-workbook) will allow you to convert named range into address

Comment: This can happen with different files too or whether you wanted to import from Access to Excel. Since you are getting data from excel files, simply make a copy of the excel files (will not fail regardless of the files are open or not) and then open the copied files or use them to enter the data, once done delete the copied files